# Maximal hexagonal dot pattern

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, hexagonal-grid

### Challenge

Imagine a hexagonal grid as shown below. Let's call such a grid has size \$n\$ if it has \$n\$ dots on one side. The following is one of size 3:

```
  - - -
 - - - -
- - - - -
 - - - -
  - - -
```

Then, pick as many dots as possible on the grid so that no two dots are adjacent. For size 3, the maximum is 7 dots:

```
  - * -          * - *
 * - - *        - - - -
- - * - -  or  * - * - *
 * - - *        - - - -
  - * -          * - *
```

Your task is to output such a grid. For a size-\$n\$ hexagon, the output must contain exactly [A002061(n)](https://oeis.org/A002061) = \$n^2-n+1\$ non-adjacent dots. The corresponding maximal pattern can be found [in this image linked on the OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A002061/a002061.png) (imagine this: dissect all the hexagons there into triangles, remove one outermost layer of triangles, and pick the centers of original hexagons). The corresponding ASCII-art output must look like the following, modulo rotation/reflection:

```
n = 1
*

n = 2
 * - 
- - *
 * - 

n = 3 (following or alternative shown above)
  * - *  
 - - - - 
* - * - *
 - - - - 
  * - *  

n = 4
   * - - *   
  - - * - -  
 - * - - * - 
* - - * - - *
 - * - - * - 
  - - * - -  
   * - - *   

n = 5
    - * - - *    
   * - - * - -   
  - - * - - * -  
 - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - -
 - * - - * - - * 
  - - * - - * -  
   * - - * - -   
    - * - - *    

n = 6
     - * - - * -     
    * - - * - - *    
   - - * - - * - -   
  - * - - * - - * -  
 * - - * - - * - - * 
- - * - - * - - * - -
 * - - * - - * - - * 
  - * - - * - - * -  
   - - * - - * - -   
    * - - * - - *    
     - * - - * -     

n = 7
      * - - * - - *      
     - - * - - * - -     
    - * - - * - - * -    
   * - - * - - * - - *   
  - - * - - * - - * - -  
 - * - - * - - * - - * - 
* - - * - - * - - * - - *
 - * - - * - - * - - * - 
  - - * - - * - - * - -  
   * - - * - - * - - *   
    - * - - * - - * -    
     - - * - - * - -     
      * - - * - - *      

n = 8
       - * - - * - - *       
      * - - * - - * - -      
     - - * - - * - - * -     
    - * - - * - - * - - *    
   * - - * - - * - - * - -   
  - - * - - * - - * - - * -  
 - * - - * - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * - - * - -
 - * - - * - - * - - * - - * 
  - - * - - * - - * - - * -  
   * - - * - - * - - * - -   
    - * - - * - - * - - *    
     - - * - - * - - * -     
      * - - * - - * - -      
       - * - - * - - *       

n = 9
        - * - - * - - * -        
       * - - * - - * - - *       
      - - * - - * - - * - -      
     - * - - * - - * - - * -     
    * - - * - - * - - * - - *    
   - - * - - * - - * - - * - -   
  - * - - * - - * - - * - - * -  
 * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * 
- - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - -
 * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * 
  - * - - * - - * - - * - - * -  
   - - * - - * - - * - - * - -   
    * - - * - - * - - * - - *    
     - * - - * - - * - - * -     
      - - * - - * - - * - -      
       * - - * - - * - - *       
        - * - - * - - * -        

n = 10
         * - - * - - * - - *         
        - - * - - * - - * - -        
       - * - - * - - * - - * -       
      * - - * - - * - - * - - *      
     - - * - - * - - * - - * - -     
    - * - - * - - * - - * - - * -    
   * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - *   
  - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - -  
 - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - 
* - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - *
 - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - 
  - - * - - * - - * - - * - - * - -  
   * - - * - - * - - * - - * - - *   
    - * - - * - - * - - * - - * -    
     - - * - - * - - * - - * - -     
      * - - * - - * - - * - - *      
       - * - - * - - * - - * -       
        - - * - - * - - * - -        
         * - - * - - * - - *
```

### I/O and rules

You can use any two distinct non-whitespace chars for marked and unmarked dots respectively. Trailing spaces on each line and leading/trailing whitespaces are allowed. Outputting a list of lines, and outputting integer charcodes instead of the corresponding chars are also allowed.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
ＮθＧ↙↘→→↗↖θ⎇﹪θ³“⟲∧ＬＶoIＧ；”“⟲∧⦄≧Σ¶ζ；
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orID@nMj0/T8PKJb88zyc1rURHAcwMykzPALHR6dACBAuivFBHISS1KC@xqFLDNz@lNCdfAyhirKmjoKSloKugG5MHJIEsJaAAmAEWALKUNDWt//83@69blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: After reading in `n`, the code simply draws a hexagon using one of two fill patterns depending on whether `n` is a multiple of 3; if it is, the fill pattern has the `*` one `-` in from the corner, otherwise it has the `*` in the top left corner.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 92 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:[l:=' '*(n-i)+('- * - '*n)[n%3%2+i<<1:][:n+i<<1]]+(n>i+1and[*f(n,i+1),l]or[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoIwEEDRq8yGdIaCobIxDXiR2kUNVseUKWnYePqK7v7b/O2zv7KMl63UGucU1vsSQDqeB@uSnRWoFqVn0qh6aKE/LOSkGZuz5mky1jsr//Jeo1xZmyCLayMeE22oSz4X56nGXICBBUqQ5wPNQBa2wrKjuok6vTMLRmQi/TPVLw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 84 bytes

```hs
f n=[[" * - -"!!mod(i+gcd 3n)6|i<-[1,3..2*y]++[4*y..2*y+4*n-4]]|y<-abs<$>[1-n..n-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcaxDoIwFAXQX7kQBm19TSqEqfgFOjk2HaqINNInERya8O818Uxn9MvrMU05D@DO2hICBCqLIr77XZDPe4@a9@0WDFl9qJU6iuSktI1I/8tGMDXObcmQvy2mOllNrBSTdi5HHxgdop8vmL/rdf2cGRUGtPkH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>27</s>  26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
3ḍ6_BṙN€ṁ"Ḥ’rƊK€ṭ"Ḷ⁶ẋƊṚŒḄY
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer and prints using `0` as `*` and `1` as `-`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/44Y5es3inhztn@j1qWvNwZ6PSwx1LHjXMLDrW5Q0WWAsU2PaocdvDXd3Huh7unHV00sMdLZH/gToB)** Or see [a few](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/44Y5es3inhztn@j1qWvNwZ6PSwx1LHjXMLDrW5Q0WWAsU2PaocdvDXd3Huh7unHV00sMdLZH/D7e7Pdy52CDrUcNcLSDDEMTQ1cx61LiPi@v/f0MDAA) with `*` and `-` in place of `0` and `1`.

#### How?

```
3ḍ6_BṙN€ṁ"Ḥ’rƊK€ṭ"Ḷ⁶ẋƊṚŒḄY - Main Link: positive integer, n
3ḍ                         - three divides (n)? -> 1 if n is a multiple of three else 0
  6                        - six
   _                       - subtract -> 5 if n is a multiple of three else 6
    B                      - to binary -> 101 (i.e. "-*-") ...else 110 (i.e. "--*")
      N€                   - negate each (of implicit [1..n]) -> [-1,-2,...,-n]
     ṙ                     - rotate (110 or 101) left by (each of those) -> Patterns (one for each row of bottom half of a hexagon)
             Ɗ             - last three links as a monad, f(n):
          Ḥ                -   double -> 2n
           ’               -   decrement -> 2n-1
            r              -   (2n-1) inclusive range (n) -> [2n-1..n]
         "                 - zip (Patterns) and (range) applying, f(Pattern, i): 
        ṁ                  -   mould like -> resized rows using repetition
              K€           - join each with space characters -> Rows
                     Ɗ     - last three links as a monad, f(n):
                  Ḷ        -   lowered range -> [0..n-1]
                   ⁶       -   space character
                    ẋ      -   repeat -> leading spaces for bottom half
                 "         - zip (Rows) and (leading spaces) applying, f(row, spaces): 
                ṭ          -   tack (row) to (spaces)
                      Ṛ    - reverse -> top of the hexagon
                       ŒḄ  - bounce -> whole hexagon
                         Y - join with newline characters
                           - implicit, smashing print
```